# solving an integral in terms of the hypergeometric function

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

I am reading a paper which seems to suggest that the integral

$$\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} z_1^{c_1-1} z_2^{c_2-1} \exp{\left\{-\frac{c_3}{2} z_1 - \frac{c_4}{2} z_2 - \frac{c_5}{2} \sqrt{z_1z_2}\right\}} dz_1 dz_2$$

can be solved in terms of the hypergeometric function ${_2}F_1$. If $c_5=0$ it is easy to solve the integral in terms of the gamma function.

However, for positive $c_5$ I cannot see what steps are involved in deriving a solution. Can someone please explain?

Thank you.

Comment: In the application, $c_1=c_2$ a positive integer. That permits a simple, elementary derivation by change of variables $z_i=u_i^2/c_{i+2}$ and noting the integrand is a higher $\rho$ derivative of $\exp(-1/2(u_1^2+u_2^2-2\rho u_1u_2)),$ whose value is easily obtained from the Binormal distribution (in terms of Arcsine and $1/\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$) for $|\rho|\lt 1.$ Whence you (a) obtain an expression in terms of elementary functions and (b) by expanding $(1-\rho^2)^{-1/2}$ with the Binomial Theorem and differentiating term by term, you get the linear combination of Hypergeometric functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all constants are positive, we can let $z_{1,2} = 2 t_{1,2}/c_{3,4}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
I(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5) &\equiv \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_0^\infty z_1^{c_1-1} z_2^{c_2-1} \exp \left[-\frac{c_3}{2} z_1 -\frac{c_4}{2} z_2 -\frac{c_5}{2} \sqrt{z_1 z_2} \right] \, \mathrm{d} z_1 \, \mathrm{d} z_2 \\
&= \frac{2^{c_1+c_2}}{c_3^{c_1} c_4^{c_2}} \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_0^\infty t_1^{c_1-1} t_2^{c_2-1} \exp \left[-t_1 -t_2 -\frac{c_5}{\sqrt{c_3 c_4}} \sqrt{t_1 t_2} \right] \, \mathrm{d} t_1 \, \mathrm{d} t_2 \, .
\end{align}
Now we use the exponential series to reduce the integrals to Gamma functions:
\begin{align}
I(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5) &= \frac{2^{c_1+c_2}}{c_3^{c_1} c_4^{c_2}} \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-c_5/\sqrt{c_3 c_4})^n}{n!} \int \limits_0^\infty t_1^{c_1 + n/2 - 1} \mathrm{e}^{-t_1} \, \mathrm{d} t_1 \int \limits_0^\infty t_2^{c_2 + n/2 - 1}\mathrm{e}^{-t_2} \, \mathrm{d} t_2 \\
&= \frac{2^{c_1+c_2}}{c_3^{c_1} c_4^{c_2}} \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1 + n/2) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2 + n/2) \frac{(-c_5/\sqrt{c_3 c_4})^n}{n!} \\
&\equiv \frac{2^{c_1+c_2}}{c_3^{c_1} c_4^{c_2}} f(c_1,c_2,c_5/\sqrt{c_3 c_4}) \, .
\end{align}
Note that this manipulation is only valid within the radius of convergence of the series, i.e. for $c_5/\sqrt{c_3 c_4} < 2$ (this follows from the asymptotic behaviour of the Gamma functions). By analytic continuation, the final result will be valid for all positive values of the parameters, however.

In order to find $f$ we split the series into even and odd terms:
\begin{align}
f(c_1,c_2,x) &= \sum \limits_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1 + n/2) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2 + n/2) \frac{(-x)^n}{n!} \\
&= \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1 + k) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2 + k) \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!} - x \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1 + 1/2 + k) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2 + 1/2 + k) \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k+1)!} \, .
\end{align}
Then we use
\begin{align}
(2k)! &= 4^k \frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}(1/2 + k)} {\operatorname{\Gamma}(1/2)} k! \, , \\
(2k+1)! &= 4^k \frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}(3/2 + k)} {\operatorname{\Gamma}(3/2)} k!
\end{align}
to write
\begin{align}
f(c_1,c_2,x) &= \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2) \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1 + k) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2 + k) \operatorname{\Gamma}(1/2)}{\operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2) \operatorname{\Gamma}(1/2 + k)} \frac{(x^2/4)^k}{k!} \\
& \phantom{={}} - x \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1 + 1/2) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2 + 1/2) \sum \limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1 + 1/2 + k) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2 + 1/2 + k) \operatorname{\Gamma}(3/2)}{\operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1+1/2) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2+1/2) \operatorname{\Gamma}(3/2 + k)} \frac{(x^2/4)^k}{k!} \\
&= \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2) \, {}_2 \! \operatorname{F}_1 (c_1,c_2;1/2;x^2/4) \\
&\phantom{={}} - x \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1 + 1/2) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2 + 1/2) \, {}_2 \! \operatorname{F}_1 (c_1 + 1/2 ,c_2 + 1/2 ;3/2;x^2/4) \, .
\end{align}
Therefore, the final result (valid for $c_i > 0$, $i \in \{1,\dots,5\}$) is
\begin{align}
I(c_1,c_2,c_3,c_4,c_5) &= \frac{2^{c_1+c_2}}{c_3^{c_1} c_4^{c_2}} \left[\operatorname{\Gamma}(c_1) \operatorname{\Gamma}(c_2) \, {}_2 \! \operatorname{F}_1 \left(c_1,c_2;\frac{1}{2};\frac{c_5^2}{4c_3c_4}\right) \right. \\
& \phantom{=\frac{2^{c_1+c_2}}{c_3^{c_1} c_4^{c_2}} \left[\vphantom{\left(c_1,c_2;\frac{1}{2};\frac{c_5^2}{4c_3c_4}\right)}\right.} \left. - \frac{c_5}{\sqrt{c_3c_4}} \operatorname{\Gamma}\left(c_1 + \frac{1}{2}\right) \operatorname{\Gamma}\left(c_2 + \frac{1}{2}\right) \, {}_2 \! \operatorname{F}_1 \left(c_1 + \frac{1}{2},c_2 + \frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2};\frac{c_5^2}{4 c_3 c_4}\right) \right] \, .
\end{align}

Comment: $\,_2\text F_1(a,b;\frac12;z)$ is a Legendre function from [this identity](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/03/06/01/0029/). It’s [derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=ddz+2F1%28a%2Cb%2C1%2F2%2Cz%29) will also simplify $\,_2\text F_1(a,b;\frac32;z)$

Comment: Thank you very much CYT!